# how to display items only from selected categories in php?

Tags: php, html, css, mysql, database

```php
<?php

     $con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root'); 
     mysqli_select_db($con,'tims');  

     $query = "SELECT * FROM products p JOIN categories c ON p.c_id = c.c_id";

     $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

     $num=mysqli_num_rows($result);

     if ($num>0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>

            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12 col-xl-6">

                    <div class="single-product-wrapper">
                        <!-- Product Image -->
                        <div class="product-img">
                            <img src="<?php echo $row['image'] ?>" alt="" />;
                            <img src="<?php echo $row['image2'] ?>" alt="" class="hover-img" />
                        </div>
                        <!-- Product Description -->
                        <div class="product-description d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
                            <!-- Product Meta Data -->
                            <div class="product-meta-data">
                                <div class="line"></div>
                                <p class="product-price"> &#8377;<?php echo $row['price'];  ?> </p>
                                <a href="product-details.php?action=add&p_id=<?php echo $row['p_id']; ?> ">
                                    <h6> <?php echo $row['title'] ?> </h6>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Ratings & Cart -->
                            <div class="ratings-cart text-right">
                                <div class="ratings">
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>                                   
                                </div>
                                <div class="cart">
                                    <a href="cart.html" name="add-to-cart" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Add to Cart"><img src="img/core-img/cart.png" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </div>

            <?php
          }

          } else { echo "0 results";}

             ?>
```

---

this is my current code. it displays every item from the table. i want only from specified category.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to:

`$query = "SELECT * FROM products p JOIN categories c ON p.c_id = c.c_id WHERE c.c_id=<YOUR_CATEGORY_ID_HERE>";`